# ng-repeat does nothing

Tags: angularjs

Re-factored my Angular app to pass in essential data via a factory service. Now suddenly The ng-repeat doesn't output anything to the page, it doesn't run at all, and I get no error messages! What happened?

```
<ul ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <li  class="section_title {{section.active}}" >
        {{section.name}}
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li class="tutorial_title {{tutorial.active}}" ng-click="loadFromMenu([$parent.$index, $index])" ng-repeat="tutorial in AppData.section.tutorials">
            {{tutorial.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>


    var Tutorials = angular.module('Tutorials', ['functions', 'tutorials']);

Tutorials.factory("AppData", function(){
    return { 
        sectionNumber: 0,
        tutorialNumber: 0,
        questionNumber: 0,
        sections: sections
    }
})

Tutorials.run(function(AppData){loadFromMenu([0,0, true], AppData);})

function loadFromMenu (tut, AppData) {
    if (tut[1] === AppData.tutorialNumber && tut[0] === AppData.sectionNumber && !tut[2]) {//if clicked on already playing tut
        return;
    } 
    if (tut[1] !== undefined && tut[0] !== undefined) {
        AppData.tutorialNumber = tut[1];
        AppData.sectionNumber = tut[0];
    }
    var section = AppData.sections[tut[0]];
    for (var x in AppData.sections) {
        AppData.sections[x].active = "inactive";
        for (var y in AppData.sections[x].tutorials){
            AppData.sections[x].tutorials[y].active = "inactive";
        }
    }
    section.active = "active";
    section.tutorials[tut[1]].active = "active";
    //$scope.$apply();
    AppData.questionNumber = 0;
    if (AppData.sectionNumber === 1){
        conjugationController();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post your controller and `loadFromMenu`?

Comment: loadFromMenu() is the only controller relevant to the markup here, I posted it. Originally I had one big controller on the body element and everything else happened inside that, I got rid of that and it stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, your problem is that you actually *aren't* using a controller. A controller is how we programmatically access the scope, to which we assign what we get from services. Views are also tied to scopes. So when you say `ng-repeat="section in sections"`, it's looking for a property on the current scope called `sections`. In most cases, this would correspond to something in your controller that said `$scope.sections = ...`. I see nothing like this in your code. Here's how it should work.

```html
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <li  class="section_title {{section.active}}" >
      {{section.name}}
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li class="tutorial_title {{tutorial.active}}" ng-click="loadFromMenu([$parent.$index, $index])" ng-repeat="tutorial in AppData.section.tutorials">
        {{tutorial.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(PS: nesting ULs the way you did is not really valid HTML; you'll want to put the inner UL in an LI.)

Now I don't know what exists outside the `ul`, so I just made it a `div`, where we told the view which controller to assign to that section of the page. So now our controller must place those variables on the scope:

```js
Tutorials.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( AppData ) {
  $scope.sections = AppData.sections;
});
```

And now it will work. As for the rest of your `loadFromMenu` function, most of that you'll want to port to your controller, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that `run` block or with the `loadFromMenu` function. So here is a general principle: generic manipulation of the service data should occur in the service.

Feel free to post a comment with more info and I'll update this answer, but the reason the ngRepeat doesn't work is because you have no controller and your `sections` variable was never assigned to the scope.